# Improve performance of exponentiation

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a rather simple function (see code below) which is employed by an MCMC, meaning it is called millions of times. For what I can tell, most of the time is consumed exponentiating arrays and I can't think of a way to improve its performance. It currently eats up ~15% of the total MCMC runtime, so every bit of improvement counts.

Can this function be made any faster?

```
import numpy as np
import time as t

def f1(abc, emax, rnd, arr):
    """This function should be as fast as possible"""

    # Only the first 3 sub-arrays are modified
    final_arr = []
    for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(abc):

        # This is an 'error' obtained through this function
        # It always uses arr[0], but the a,b,c values change
        sigma = a * np.exp(b * arr[0]) + c

        # Clip values at 'emax'
        sigma[sigma > emax[i]] = emax[i]

        # Add the errors to arr[i], 'rnd' is a random array
        # of floats normally distributed with mean 0 and
        # stdev 1.
        final_arr.append(arr[i] + rnd[:len(arr[i])] * sigma)

    return final_arr

# Some initial data with the proper shape. This data does
# not change with iterations
emax = [.05, .1, .17]
abc = [
    [0.01068788, 0.13260967, -0.03015476],
    [0.01068788, 0.13260967, -0.03015476],
    [0.01068788, 0.13260967, -0.03015476]]
rnd = np.random.normal(0., 1., 1000000)

t1, t2 = 0., 0.
for _ in range(10000):

    # Array of data with proper shape.
    # This array changes with successive iterations.
    arr1 = np.random.uniform(10., 30., (1, 1000))
    arr2 = np.random.uniform(0., .3, (9, 1000))
    arr = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2))

    s = t.time()
    f1(abc, emax, rnd, arr)
    t1 += t.time() - s

print(t1)
```

Comment: 15% doesn't actually seem too much, really, for the actual calculation.

Comment: You may want to make `abc` a numpy array, or list of numpy arrays, which will avoid conversions to numpy arrays *each time* on the line with the exponential.

Comment: Ultimately, you'll just want to do this with something like Cython, Numba or code it directly in C.

Comment: While I'm not sure about speed-up improvement requests, your question may be better suited at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I'm trimming from every function involved in the MCMC, starting from those that eat up the most time. This is the one that comes in second place, the other ones I've already modified as much as possible for performance.

Comment: There is also [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html); it may be faster (certainly more readable).

Comment: I've tried np.clip(), it is slower.

Comment: I'm guessing your loop can be replaced with NumPy broadcasting and some 2D-array calculations, but I'm not sure whether it would actually be faster: your `abc` list is so small, the loop is near instantaneous (and you could even consider unrolling it instead).

Comment: For scalar values `math.exp` is faster.  `np.exp` is better with big arrays.

Comment: By the way, consider using `timeit`: it will create the loop for you, and you can set it to use random input as well.

Comment: @hpaulj but I'm exponentiating an array (`arr[0]`)

Comment: Does variables like `abc` or `final_arr` really have to be lists or could numpy arrays also used instead?

Comment: numpy arrays are fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Numba for improving performance. With quite simple changes to the code (writing simple loops, avoiding lists,...) you could easily get a significant speedup.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

emax = np.array([.05, .1, .17])
abc = np.array([
    [0.01068788, 0.13260967, -0.03015476],
    [0.01068788, 0.13260967, -0.03015476],
    [0.01068788, 0.13260967, -0.03015476]])

rnd = np.random.normal(0., 1., 1000000)
arr1 = np.random.uniform(10., 30., (1, 1000))
arr2 = np.random.uniform(0., .3, (9, 1000))
arr = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2))

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def f1_nb(abc, emax, rnd, arr):
    final_arr = np.empty((abc.shape[0],arr.shape[1]))
    for i in nb.prange(abc.shape[0]):
        a=abc[i,0]
        b=abc[i,1]
        c=abc[i,2]

        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            sigma = a * np.exp(b * arr[0,j]) + c

            if sigma>emax[i]:
                 sigma=emax[i]

            final_arr[i,j]=arr[i,j] + rnd[j] * sigma

    return final_arr
```

**Timings**

```
#warmup, first call takes longer
res_1=f1_nb(abc, emax, rnd, arr)
%timeit f1_nb(abc, emax, rnd, arr)
#parallel=True
#13 µs ± 81.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
#parallel=False
#18.9 µs ± 94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

#Your implementation
%timeit f1(abc, emax, rnd, arr)
#61.3 µs ± 277 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Parallelization isn't really helpful here since the arrays are too small, but might make sense in the outer loop.

Comment: Thank you max. I've never used `numba` nor any other Python compiler but I think I've reached the point where I can no longer extract performance out of `numpy`, so I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting to vectorize the operations and save 30% of computation time. Just make sure you create numpy arrays from your value lists first:

```
def f2(abc, eamx, rnd, arr):
    sigma = abc[:, 0, None] * np.exp(abc[:, 1, None] * arr[0, :]) + abc[:, 2, None]
    sigma = np.clip(sigma, a_min=None, a_max=emax[:, None])
    final_arr = arr[:len(sigma), :]
    return final_arr + rnd[:final_arr.shape[1]] * sigma

emax = np.asarray(emax)
abc = np.asarray(abc)

np.allclose(f1(abc, emax, rnd, arr), f2(abc, emax, rnd, arr))
# True

%timeit f1(abc, emax, rnd, arr)
78.3 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit f2(abc, emax, rnd, arr)
54.8 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you Nils. Your code works but I'm getting no improvements with this version (1% at most). On a 10000 loop they both take ~3.18 s on my machine.

Comment: Can you reproduce the gain using the `%timeit` code I used? If yes you must be spending time somewhere else...

Comment: I'm wrapping each function call separately with it own `t.time()` so I don't that's it. I'll try with `%timeit`.

Comment: I'm getting a 5% improvement at best with `%timeit`. Can you reproduce that 30% with another `arr`? This array changes with every call, which is why I define it inside the `for` block in my original code.

Comment: Often a small loop on a complex task is competitive with the 'vectorized/no-loop' equivalent.  There's a tradeoff between a few iterations and a more complicated memory management.